# React-native-mlkit-ocr issue with detectFromUri

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have created a text recognition app with react native expo ,
I am using** react-native-mlkit-ocr** , Further I am getting issue with
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'detectFromUri')
Here is my code

```
import { View, Text , Pressable } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { styles } from './stying';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
// import MlkitOcr from 'react-native-mlkit-ocr';
import  MlkitOcr  from 'react-native-mlkit-ocr';
import MLKit from 'react-native-mlkit-ocr';
export default function Main() {
    const [url,setUrl] = useState("");
  


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable style={[
        ({pressed}) =>[ 
          {
            backgroundColor: pressed ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)' : 'white',
          }],
          {

            backgroundColor : 'black',
            // height :60,
            borderRadius:10,
            padding : 10,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            alignSelf : 'center',
          }
      ]} onPress={async ()=>{
        try {
          
            // setUrl("");
            let res = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
            console.log(res);
            if(!res.canceled)
            {
              setUrl(res.assets[0].uri);
              console.log("url is 1 --" + url)
            }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }


      }} >
      <Text style={{
        fontSize : 20,
        color : 'white'
      }}><Ionicons name="md-image" size={30} color="white" /> Select your image</Text>
    </Pressable>
    <Pressable  style={[
        ({pressed}) =>[ 
          {
            backgroundColor: pressed ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)' : 'white',
          }],
          {

            backgroundColor : 'black',
            // height :60,
            borderRadius:10,
            padding : 10,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            alignSelf : 'center',
          }
      ]} onPress={async ()=>{
        try {
          
          console.log( "url is :- "+ url);
          let txt = "";
          if(url)
          txt =  MLKit.detectFromUri(url);
          console.log(txt);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
    }} ><Text style={{
      color : 'white',
      fontSize : 22,
      padding:10,
    }}>Generate image</Text></Pressable>
    </View>
  )
}
```

i followed the documentation carefully but i always get the following error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'detectFromUri') can someone help me i've been trying to find a solution for days